# Applying a functional over an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The space $\ell^p$ has a Schauder basis and so we can uniquely express any element of $\ell^p$ as: $$x= \sum^\infty_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{e_i}$$ Where $(e_i)$ is the Schauder basis for $\ell^p$.

My question is, if we apply a functional in the dual space of $\ell^p$ to $x$:

$$f(x)= f \left(\sum^\infty_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{e_i}\right)$$

My text then motivates the next step by saying "since $f$ is linear and bounded", we get:

$$f(x)= \sum^\infty_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{f(e_i)}$$

I am unsure whether boundedness really plays a role here with this step.

A non-rigorous way of thinking about the above step would be:

$$f(x)= f \left({\alpha_1}{e_1}+{\alpha_2}{e_2}+{\alpha_3}{e_3}+...\right)\implies$$

$$f(x)= f ({\alpha_1}{e_1})+f({\alpha_2}{e_2})+f({\alpha_3}{e_3})+...\implies$$

$$f(x)= {\alpha_1}f ({e_1})+{\alpha_2}f({\alpha_2}{e_2})+{\alpha_3}f({e_3})+... = \sum^\infty_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{f(e_i)}$$

All following from the linearity of $f\in \ell^{p'} $. The use of '$...$' is bothering me.

Is there a better way of thinking about distributing a function over an infinite sum ? Is boundedness playing a role that I am unaware of ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the definition of a Schauder basis is the convergence in norm, i.e. with $x_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i$, then $\|x-x_n\| \to 0$, so that $f(x) = f(x_n) + f(x-x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i  f(e_i) + f(x-x_n)$ . the last term $\to 0$ since $|f(x-x_n)| < \|x-x_n\| \ \|f_n\|$, hence the series $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i f( e_i) $ converges (conditionally)  and is $= f(x)$

Comment: As @user1952009 pointed out, boundedness of $f$ ensures convergence of the series $\sum_{i\ge 1}\alpha_if(e_i)$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you very much ! That is a more subtle step than one might expect. You are welcome to repost your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: nothing really complicated. think this way :  $f$ continuous  means that $x_n \to x \implies f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Comment: so the problem reduces to : understanding the definition of continuity on a Banach space, and that bounded = countinuous, and recognizing where to apply all this in the your exercice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is to recognize that when you write $$x= \sum^\infty_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{e_i},$$ you mean 
$$
x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum^n_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{e_i}
$$
(in other words, *a series is not a sum, it is a limits of sums*). 
This also requires that you recognize which topology you are using for the limit, which in this case is the norm topology.

So your equality is in reality
$$
f(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}{\alpha_i}{f(e_i)}.
$$
The equality is indeed true because, as $f$ is bounded, it is continuous.